# UDP server/client real time performance in C

Tags: c, sockets, udp

I want to test the performance of server/client arhitecture that I wrote but I have problems with non-blocking sockets. When I use fcntl I can not run client and server to work at the same time. While I run server client has already sent 5000 replies back although the server is not start to stream. How
can I make difference on client when server isn't turned on and when packet is lost? In my code client
behaves  same.
On the other side, when I don't use fcntl then If I client doesn't receive packet
it blocks and wait on that packet, he even don't sent a reply back. I want that
client send back reply and to continue to receiving packets.

I dont want to use sleep because I need real time performance.

I'm wondering how real application are working, what is trick to implement this?

Thx

server

```
fcntl(socket,F_SETFL,O_NONBLOCK);

while(1){

    sendto clients
    pthread_create(reply_processing)

}

reply_processing(){

    recvfrom_clients

}
```

client

```
fcntl(sd,F_SETFL,O_NONBLOCK);


while(1){

    bytes = recvfrom server, buf

    if(nbytes != -1){

        if(buf > = 512) write
        else EOF return 1;



    }else{

        lost++
        nack sent


    }
}
```

Comment: Your question, code and understanding of network comms, is very confused.  If you don't want server or client to just send datagrams while the peer is not running, why are you using UDP?  To detect a server<>client 'connection' you must add another protocol on top of UDP.

Comment: I'0m using udp because of real time requirements. Is there a way to detect server activity using UDP?